# Как сделать такой блок без абсолютного позиционирования

Tags: html, css

Как сделать такое БЕЗ использования абсолютного позиционирования. Как "Поиск напарника" поместить на центр страницы, а не центр оставшейся площади для него  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr max-content 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: end;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.main {
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="side"></div>
  <div class="main">
    Поиск напарника
  </div>

  <div class="side">
    <span>Посмотреть мои заявки</span>
    <button>Создать зявку</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Это не решает проблему. Если уменьшать ширину экрана, то текст ползет друг на друга

Comment: О какой проблеме идет речь? Вопрос поставлен очень четко - как сделать такой блок без абсолютного позиционирования. Если проблема с перекрытием теста, то об этом было бы написано в вопросе и БЕЗ акцента на абсолютном позиционировании.

Comment: Если без шуток, то опишите нормально вопрос. Напишите о вашей проблема, напишите что должно происходить с кнопкой и текстом при уменьшении ширины. Посмотрите апдейт в моем ответе, это конечно попытка угадать что вам нужно, но вдруг получилось...

Comment: @UserTest013 Первый вариант удалите если будет норм)). Считаю не нужно оставлять неправильные варианты чисто для открытия смысла спора в комментах)).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте:

```
display: flex
```

вместо `grid`