# Выравнивание по флексбоксу

Tags: html, css, flexbox, бэм, adaptive-design

Существует мобайл-версия шапки следующего вида:

```
<header class="header">                   // .header {display: flex}
    <div class="header__logo"></div>
    <div class="header__burger"></div>
</header>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как отцентрировать блоки так, чтобы лого было ровно по-центру, а бургер-меню было прижато к краю блока `<header>`. Разумеется, можно абсолютно позиционировать дивы, но хочется использовать исключительно flexbox технологию

Comment: Уже был такой вопрос, там целых 2 варианта описывали

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи, прикрепите ссылки, пожалуйста

Comment: Вот нашёл, только там на grid - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1510686/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%b0%d0%b1%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такой вариант придумал). А ту ссылку я не нашёл.

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
}
.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.header__logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
  background: green;
  margin: auto;
}
.header:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
}
.header__burger {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
    <div class="header__logo"></div>
    <div class="header__burger"></div>
</header>
```